# i would like to do the generic search option in repository pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

Here i implemented generic repository pattern for do the CRUD operation at the same time , i would like to do the search option as well, anyone can you tell me query to do generic search options, my code is below

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    T GetById(object Id);
    T Insert(T obj);
    void Delete(object Id);
    T Update(T obj);
    void Save();
    long Count();
}
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private PegasusPlusEntities context;
    private DbSet<T> dbSet;
    public Repository()
    {
        context = new PegasusPlusEntities();
        dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return dbSet.ToList();
    }
    public T GetById(object id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }
    public T Insert(T obj)
    {
        dbSet.Add(obj);
        Save();
        return obj;
    }
    public void Delete(object id)
    {
        T entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
        Delete(entityToDelete);
    }
    public void Delete(T entityToDelete)
    {
        if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
        }
        dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
    }
    public T Update(T obj)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(obj);
        context.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
        Save();
        return obj;
    }
    public long Count()
    {
        return dbSet.Count();
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        try
        {
            context.SaveChanges();

        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {


                }
            }
        }
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (context != null)
            {
                context.Dispose();
                context = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

thanks in advance...

Comment: read up on how to use linq and lambda expressions with EF

Comment: A repository shouldn't save data (which may surprise you). The commits are too fine-grained so you'll have a hard time doing multiple commits in one transaction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this but here is a simple example

Add a method to the current interface to allow for generic search

```
IEnumerable<T> Search(Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate);
```

A simple implementation can look like this

```
public IEnumerable<T> Search(Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate) {
    return dbSet.Where(predicate).ToList();
}
```

An example of it in use would be

```
var repository = new Repository<Person>();
var searchResults = repository.Search(p => p.FirstName == "John" && p.LastName == "Doe");
```

Comment: Do you know how it can be done which involves join in two or more tables?

Comment: @Nkosi what would you say to people who think that this kind of abstraction leads to bad consequences? Especially if you were to do something like this with the repository pattern?

Comment: @Nkosi is there any chance we could have an offline chat about this? This is a real area of contention for many developers and it looks as though you've delved in to this.

Comment: @ChristianFindlay You are right, there are differing camps on how this approach can be seen as a leaky abstraction, but IMO it all depends on who, where, and how it is to be used/applied.

Comment: @ChristianFindlay I still use this approach as a means of applying filters and have had no issues with it. The underlying store is of no consequence if it is not exposed (leaked) as `IQuerable`. I personally prefer using the expression to apply filters in code.

Comment: @Nkosi I got berated for asking a similar kind of question [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/412877/express-sql-query-as-abstract-object-model?noredirect=1#comment909784_412877) . My question is not exactly the same, but the spirit of the question was. The spirit of the question is about how one would abstract a query away from the infrastructure layer. Expressions are one way to achieve that. But, even then, people are scornful of such an approach.